# Should a question with constructive comments be prevented from deletion?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-questions

Twice lately I posted helpful comments on a couple of questions (same OP for both, second question actually being a followup of the first).

Those comments were more like spot-on quick tips than detailed, dignified answers, hence I posted them as such. They indeed guided OP to the solution of his/her problem. Some of those comments were even upvoted at some point.

Nevertheless, quickly after getting the information (s)he wanted, OP quickly deleted the question from SO.

I understand as of now the deletion locking mechanism is about positive answers, never about comments. Since I'm not sure these deletions were either fair or justified, and I feel somehow SO lost a little bit of its value in the process, I come to seek your thoughts on the matter. **Should a question with upvoted comments (but no answer) be allowed to be deleted at all ?**

Comment: Most of upvoted comments under close/delete-worthy questions are either pre-written comments about the rules or spiteful remarks.

Comment: If upvoted comments prevented the roomba from doing its job, then nothing would ever get deleted except for Tumbleweed posts.

Comment: @vaultah these were not low-quality questions (not high quality either though), granted pre-written comments should be excluded somehow.

Comment: @psubsee2003 these were deleted by the OP himself for no apparent reason, except (s)he got what (s)he wanted out of it and made it go away. These are usually not deleted unless marked as such after a very long time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comments are ["second-class citizens"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193666/236218) on SE and you should not be putting content into comments if you want that content to stick around. If they indeed solve the problem then post it as an answer and if that answer gets upvoted then that will prevent the OP from deleting the question and as a result also protect the content you posted.

When you answer a question in a comment you're going to have to live with the fact that it might disappear.